# NODE-RED diplaying csv splitted messages in dashboard

Tags: csv, text, node-red

I have following function code to split an incoming message payload carrying a CSV formatted string into multiple messages

```
var outputMsgs = [];
var words = msg.payload.split(",");
for (var w in words) {
  outputMsgs.push({payload:words[w]});
}
return [ outputMsgs ];
```

How to put each msg into a specific text field in dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than output a stream of messages on 1 output of the function node, you should output 1 message on multiple outputs and then wire each output to the correct Dashboard UI text node.

Change the code to remove the square brackets from around the outputMsgs

```
var outputMsgs = [];
var words = msg.payload.split(",");
for (var w in words) {
  outputMsgs.push({payload:words[w]});
}
return outputMsgs;
```

Then increase the number of outputs in the function node using the input under the function text

[image]